# What access does a Windows authenticated user in T-SQL need to create an External_Access or Unsafe Assembly?

Tags: sqlclr

I'm trying to do a POC using Sqlclr and C# to call .Net code (dll) from a stored procedure. I'm trying to write to EventLogs. I was able to create a safe assembly and then create a stored procedure wrapper around my dll. But while executing the code it failed - for Event Log access the Assembly needs to be created with an External_Access/ Unsafe permission set.

When I tried the same with an External Assembly it didn't work. So I went with the route of creating a Login from the signed dll.

- I signed the dll using Visual Studio. Under project properties signing tab, I signed it without a password (snk file).
- I then created an asymmetric key in sql with the dll.
- Using this asymmetric key I have created a Login in Master.
- I then granted this Login External Access Assembly.
- Changed Database to use the particular one in which I am trying to create the wrapper procedure
- In the next step I tried to create the Assembly with External_Access
  permission set.
- This failed with the Error Message -

Msg 300 - 
External Access Assembly Permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'

- I then tried going through the route of setting Database Trustworthy
  to ON just to check if the concept actually works.
- This failed with the same exception.

My question is does my Windows authenticated login need to have more permissions to be able to set the External_Access permissions. Does it require an SA account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, did you mean to run this on master (as per the error message)?

To use `TRUSTWORTHY`, the user needs **sysadmin** as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property), but it is generally a bad idea to use `TRUSTWORTHY`.

To create an assembly with `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` the login needs **EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY** permission on the server. To create the assembly as `UNSAFE` the login needs **UNSAFE ASSEMBLY** permission on the server. You can read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql).

Niels

Comment: Niels: +1. Regarding the first sentence, it is not being run in master. The permissions are checking in `master` since that is where Logins are stored and hence Server-level permissions are managed. I just reproduced this exact error message, including the `master` part, and was not in master. This has to do with both permissions noted in paragraph 3 being Server-level permissions. Regarding not using `TRUSTWORTHY`: https://ModuleSigning.info/

Comment: Thanks @NielsBerglund your answer and the linked article confirmed the access issue.

Answer (score 1):

It would help greatly to know what version of SQL Server you are using given that there was a rather significant change, security-wise, in SQL Server 2017 as it relates to creating Assemblies. I have written a series of articles explaining the overall issue in SQL Server 2017 and providing a few solutions that can be automated within Visual Studio / SSDT:

[SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 1: “CLR strict security” – The Problem](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/07/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-1-clr-strict-security/)

Part 1 is mostly explanation while parts 2 and 3 are the two methods for working within these constraints.

1. If you are using SQL Server 2017, have you tried granting the Asymmetric Key-based Login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission?
2. Did you do anything else besides `GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` for that Login? Did you `DENY` anything?
3. Another thing to try is to add the Asymmetric Key-based Login to the `sysadmin` fixed server role:

   ```sql
   ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [{LoginName}];
   ```

   While this *shouldn't* be necessary, the older documentation (2008 R2 and before) stated that it was a requirement. I have never needed to do it, but it is worth testing as it if nothing else works, it will get us closer to the actual issue. Be sure to set `TRUSTWORTHY` back to `OFF` in the DB where you turned it `ON`.

Also, you might want to review the series of articles I wrote on SQL Server Central that explain various aspects of working with SQLCLR in general:

[Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/)

Comment: Hi Solomon, Im using SQL Server 2016. It was actually your articles that got me this far. Thanks :) I will try adding sysadmin to the Login. Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't denied any permission and  I tried both the External_Access as well as the Unsafe permission.

Comment: The concern I have is that I am just logged in through a Windows account. Does executing the above need me to be the owner of the dba or some similar permission?

Comment: Are you talking about the rights that your Login has? Are you sysadmin? You might need to be temporarily to create the assembly. ..I can test that later when I get home. .

Comment: Hey Lavin! Dir you read my answer above - how your login should have the permissions as per my answer?

Comment: @LavinSharma Hey, I just tested and confirmed that YOUR login, the one executing the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement, does indeed need the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission granted in order to do this, not just `CREATE ASSEMBLY` within that DB. Sorry, I misunderstood the question. This is what Niels suggested in the 3rd paragraph of his answer. And to be clear, no, `sysadmin` is not needed for either login, yours or the Asymmetric Key-based login. Also, I will try to update my articles to clarify this point. I usually never create assemblies using non-admin Logins.

Comment: @NielsBerglund He did not get your message since you didn't include his `@` name. But I just confirmed the final point of your answer and replied to him directly above this comment indicating that.

Comment: @NielsBerglund and SolomonRutzky, thanks a lot for both your answers and also for validating what I was asking. I went through a lot of articles online but none of them mention that the login executing the create assembly should have permissions. Thanks a lot for clarifying that point. Also thanks to your series of articles Solomon, for helping me understand about Slclr.